# Regex not giving the expected output

Tags: java, regex

***Code:***

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Regex {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String data = ". Shyam and you. Lakshmi and you. Ram and you. Raju and you. ";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\.\\s(.*?and.*?)\\.\\s");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(data);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }

}
}
```

Expected output:

```
Shyam and you
Lakshmi and you
Ram and you
Raju and you
```

But the output i got was:

```
Shyam and you
Ram and you
```

Please correct me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not getting adjacent matches, because you are matching the `".\\s"` of the next pattern in the previous pattern. So, they won't be matched again.

You should use look-arounds:

```
Pattern.compile("(?<=\\.\\s)(.*?and.*?)(?=\\.\\s)");
```

Look-arounds are 0-length assertion. They won't consume the characters, but just check whether a pattern is there or not, either forward, or backward.

---

**References:**

- [Regular Expression info - Look Around](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm no regexpert, but It looks like your pattern is matching for two ., when there's only one in between each sentence.